# Checking a particualr date in a dynamic named files and creating log out of it using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

I've a file named `62810501601420200502.swt1` and in the end I have date in this format 20200502 and in front of it is just a random number which changes (dynamic). What I want is that I want to read only the date of the file and create log out of it through a shell script.

For example if today is 20200502 then I create log which says File found in the server, 
else 
if the file is not found then it simply says file not found on the server.

In the below code I have a file with a fixed name in front so I was able to create logs and other stuff.

But now my file name can be changed but date position is fixed and also the filename length is fixed.

```
#!/bin/sh

###############################################

PU=$(date +%d-%m-%Y)
Date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

###############################################


urban="/Path/of/file/PAYMENT_$PU.csv"

###############################################

if [ -f "$urban" ]; then 
echo "[$PU]  $urban file exist" >> /Mail_Scripts/mail.log
else
echo "[$Date]  $urban file does not exist" >> /Scripts/mail.log
echo "$Date,CCB,PAYMENT_$PU.csv,IP" >> /Scripts/iles.csv

fi
###############################################
```

Any suggestions or solution?

Comment: Welcome! You talk about a file .swt1 but then in your code the file is .csv.

Comment: The description does not have much to do with the code in general as `date +%Y-%m-%d` does not output something like `20200502`. `PAYMENT_` is not a random number.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity i'm using a different file now and i used to read csv from that script

Comment: @HaukeLaging I used the given shell script as a reference what i've been using till now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### bash

If you use `bash` (the shebang line calls `sh` but the question is tagged with `bash`) then you can get the eight characters before the dot with this code:

```
var=62810501601420200502.swt1
tmp="${var%.*}"
date_string="${tmp: -8}"
```

### sed

With `sh` you can use `sed`:

```
date_string="$(printf %s "$var" | sed -r 's/^(.*)(.{8})\..*$/\2/')"
```

### grep

Or with `grep`:

```
date_string="$(printf %s "$var" | grep -oP '.{8}(?=\.)')"
```